# Two div with the same height

Tags: css, html, height

after one hour of research i'm still stuck with my problem.

I want to make one menu on the left with a fixed width and variable height.
And an other div on the right with a variable width and height.

And I want to give the same height to these two div.

Here it is : [Code HTML / CSS](http://pastebin.com/fBNrNBKX)

Comment: Did you try setting the height attribute on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a [solution](http://jsbin.com/ovami4/26).

By using some css table stuff (display:table-row, display: table-cell etc).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:  Note you can replace inline style with CSS classes I just did it this way to make it easy to see what was going on.

```
<body>
    <div id="leftnav" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; width:200px;overflow:auto;"> 
    </div> 
    <div id="content" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:200px; bottom:0px; right:0px; overflow:auto;"> 
    </div> 
</body>
```

Here is an example you can preview http://jsbin.com/ovami4/edit

Comment: @aujoul_k Not sure what you mean by flotant

Comment: the only way to go variable height is to use JQuery or some sort of java library.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example here : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/luckymurari/2Ts9N/)

Basically, give a fixed height to the "container" and make overflow:hidden. Also give that height to the "nav"

Comment: variable height coz you want to accommodate images of different sizes?

Comment: You can use JS to programatically changing the height.. but not a good practice

Comment: At the right there will have variable number of category, and at the left there will have a variable number of images. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This works. You can set the height of leftnav. Rightnav can also be variable but don't forget to clear: left; before you add something after that.

```
<body>
  <div id="leftnav" style="background-color: blue; float: left; width:200px;">       
  </div> 
  <div id="content" style="background-color: red; float: left; width: auto; position: absolute; right: 0px; left: 200px;"> 
  </div> 
</body>
```

Comment: It's not what i want to do, the two div must have the same height. Exemple of your answer : http://jsfiddle.net/vpWYL/