# how to make same height of two div because one div have small text and one have more text content

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i am getting the problem of fix height. i am trying to fix the heights of two column having different content length. i am using bootstrap and don't want to use media queries for fixing the height issue. I have give padding but when the width decrease ,the height start increasing.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 news">
        <h3 style="font-weight:bold; font-size:18px;color:#172975;">NEWS</h3>
            <p style="font-size:16px; color:#162875;"> Whatsapp Drugs and Dental Authorisations >><br>
                2016 Payments And Billing Calendar >><br>
                January 2016 Newsletter >><br>
                Pharmacies Accepting Cimas >><br>
                Special Edition Pulse Magazine >><br>
                December 2015 Newletter >><br>
                Dependant Cell Numbers Registration >><br>
                Providers Accepting CIMAS Cards >><br>
                September 2014 Newsletter >><br>
                Commissioning Ceremony of the CIMAS donated<br> 
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Optometry Equipment at Sekuru Kaguvi Eye Unit >><br>
                EBOLA Haemorrhagic Fever Alert >><br>
                New Dental Treatment Policy >><br>
                Submission of Tax Clearance Certficate >><br>
                Payment of Contribution Rates >><br>
                CIMAS Air Ambulance in Pictures >><br>
                CIMAS Laboratories ISO 15189 Accreditation >><br>
                Contribution Rates >></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 linkinfo">
            <div class="text-mainbox">
                <div class="text-box1">
                    <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                </div>
                <div class="text-box2">
                    <p><span class="text">CIMAS</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;An enduring contribution.<br>We're proud of the value we create<br> through our tax and economic<br> contribution.Learn more.<br><a href="https://t.co.EvXuvPbNRL">https://t.co.EvXuvPbNRL</a></p>
                    <p class="refresh"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#172976;font-size:25px;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#172976;font-size:25px;"></i></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p style="font-size:16px;color:#8d8d8d;">Join the conversation by sending us a message or question on twitter</p>
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="@CIMAS"></textarea>
                </div>

            </form>
            <button class="btn btn-info">Talk to us</button>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this question would have been answered on SO many times over, can you please take a look? this for e.x. looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890108/two-div-with-the-same-height

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look here:

[fluid width, equal height columns](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

[bootstrap CSS example](http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)

Comment: please give coding in bootstrap

Comment: You can use the CSS with bootstrap

Comment: .row-eq-height { display: -webkit-box; display: -webkit-flex; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex; }